# Correct use of hashmap. Javascript

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I need to use hashmap for this program... the code below is running but does not include hashmap.

```
function isSubstring(string1, string2, a, b) {
  if (a == 0) return true;
  if (b == 0) return false;

  if (string1[a - 1] == string2[b - 1])
    return isSubstring(string1, string2, a - 1, 2 - 1);
  return isSubstring(string1, string2, a, b - 1);
}

let string1 = "lofri";
var punctLess = string1
  .replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "")
  .replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ");
let string2 = "hello, friend!";
let a = string1.length;
let b = string2.length;
let result = isSubstring(punctLess, string2, a, b);

if (result) {
  console.log("Yes");
} else {
  console.log("No");
}
```

This is what I've been changing:

```
function isSubstring(string1, string2, a, b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return true;
    if (b == 0)
        return false;

    if (string1[a - 1] == string2[b - 1])
        return isSubstring(string1, string2,
                a - 1, 2 - 1);
    return isSubstring(string1, string2, a, b - 1);
}

const mp = new Map();
mp.set('string1', 'ello');
mp.set('string2', 'hello, friend!')

var punctLess = mp[0].replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");

let a = mp[0].length;
let b = mp[1].length;
let result = isSubstring(punctLess, string2, a, b);

if (result){
    console.log("Yes");
} else {
    console.log("No");
}
```

I focussed on getting this to work that I forgot I had to use hashmaps. I'm new to programming and need some guidance.

Comment: What is preventing you from using hashmaps?

Comment: @ScottHunter nothing but when I try to change it, my program does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out...

```
function isSubstring(string1, string2, a, b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return true;
    if (b == 0)
        return false;

    if (string1[a - 1] == string2[b - 1])
        return isSubstring(string1, string2,
                a - 1, 2 - 1);
    return isSubstring(string1, string2, a, b - 1);
}

const mp = new Map();
mp.set('string1', ', ');
mp.set('string2', 'hello, friend!')

var punctLess = mp.get('string1').replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");

let a = mp.get('string1').length;
let b = mp.get('string2').length;
let result = isSubstring(punctLess, mp.get('string2'), a, b);

if (result){
    console.log("Yes");
} else {
    console.log("No");
}
```

The program runs and validates my input. If someone wants to perfect the code please feel free to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @BackendDev_onTheMaking, you were doing mistake in accessing the map instances that you've figured out, congratulation! I tried running your code it works and logs `No`

> Please note that, on Strings (in JavaScript) there is a method available `.includes()` which does the same task.

[refer this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)